# Concatenate all the string values returned by distinct()

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

**UPDATE / NOTE ON ANSWERS BELOW**
`pg_typeof()` on my target column was "regtype", not "text"...

So the contrived example below was a red herring. it WAS answered correctly by @richyen below. For those whose tables are NOT text, converting to text is needed, which is the accepted answer by @a_horse_with_no_name below

---

From table `myschema.thing`:

```
id | fruit  | color  | owner_id
---+--------+--------+---------
1  | apple  | red    |   100
2  | banana | yellow |   100
3  | tomato | red    |   500
4  | grape  | purple |   200
```

I'm trying to get the result:

```
colors
------------------
red,yellow,purple
```

Based on this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html

I've tried this:

```
select concat_ws(',', distinct(color)) as colors 
from myschema.thing
```

But it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's kind of confusing that your table is called `thing` and you also have a column called `thing`

Comment: @richyen ^thank you. Fixed. It's a generalized example  i made up to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `string_agg()`

```
select string_agg(distinct color::text, ',') as colors
from thing
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GLFXG32756

Comment: gives error: `function string_agg(myschema.color, unknown) does not exist`

Comment: did you try `...FROM myschema.thing`?

Comment: @yen -- Can you update with `SELECT pg_typeof(color) FROM myschema.thing`?

Comment: @yen: Don't prefix the column name with a schema name. Use it exactly as I have shown. The code certainly works: https://rextester.com/GLFXG32756

Comment: @richyen, @a_horse_with_no_name you are absolutely correct, the string_agg() works, for string columns. I did not realise this, but my target column in my real schema is of type `regtype`... it's a type the dba created. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @yen: then cast it to `text`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name THAT WORKED!!!! Thank you both so much !!!  I think maybe I should still accept richyen's answer cos my orig question was misleading? Not sure what to do now, lol...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `string_agg()`, with a `distinct` clause:

```
postgres=# create table thing (id int, color text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into thing values (1, 'red'),(2,'yellow'),(3,'red'),(4,'purple');
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# select * from thing;
 id |  color  
----+--------
  1 | red
  2 | yellow
  3 | red
  4 | purple
(4 rows)

postgres=# select string_agg(distinct color, ',') as colors from myschema.thing;
      colors       
-------------------
 purple,red,yellow
(1 row)
```

Comment: that (contrived) example works, but I can't seem to apply it to my actual schema. Does string_agg or a given schema need something special to make it work? Should I accept the answer anyway? It answers the question posed....

Comment: It's up to you.  Maybe you have a strange data type in the `color` column, and you could do `string_agg(distinct color::text, ',')`

Comment: Maybe you could update your post with your actual schema, so we can help you diagnose it?